# я написал програму на python, которая делает дабл клик. Но после ее запуска мышка начинает лагать

Tags: python

код программы:

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui
from pynput import mouse

click_enabled = False

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button == mouse.Button.left and pressed:
        print('p')
        pyautogui.click()
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('f'):
        if not click_enabled:
            click_enabled = True
            with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
                listener.join()
    else:
        click_enabled = False
```

как я говорил ранне, после ее запуска, мышка начинает лагать. Даже после ее закрытие все также. Помогает лишь перезагрузка ПК.

Comment: Добавьте минимальную паузу в ваш бесконечный цикл (хотя бы 100 мс), чтобы не занимать ядро процессора полностью.

Comment: типо так?
while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('f'):
        if not click_enabled:
            click_enabled = True
            with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
                listener.join()

Comment: Да, или в конец цикла.

Comment: не помогло. Мышка все равно очень лагает.

Comment: Попробуйте написать вот так:
```
pa.mouseDown()
tm.sleep(0.1)
pa.mouseUp()
```

Comment: пробовал, не помогает

Comment: вы загоняете программу в бесконечный цикл, поэтому появляются лаги. Т.е on_click(x, y, button, pressed) вызывается после вашего клика мышкой и тут же вы кликаете программно, что приводит к зацикливанию.

Comment: понял, спасибо. тогда как сделать так, что бы програма проигнорила второй клик?